# How do I search the name of a table, knowing only one of the table's column name in SQL?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-administration

I'm trying to find a table containing a column that I know the name to. Is there some way to do a table search using only the name of the column?

Answer (score 0):

In oracle

```
select * from user_tab_columns where column_name= '';
```

Comment: Thank you. I never heard of `user_tab_columns` before, or `column_name`. I am a beginner.

I tried running this line, but i wasn't sure why `column_name` does not work in it:
    `select table_name from all_tables where column_name = ' ';`

Could you explain?

Comment: @Phillip whch version of oracle are you using? `select * from all_tables`  does not has column information. `All_tables` gives you the list of tables. `User_tab_columns` gives you all columns in your database

Comment: try `select * from user_tab_columns where column_name= 'some_column';`

Comment: I'm using Oracle 11g. The command you gave me just now runs fine, however it doesn't do what I hoped it would. When I specify the column name I'm searching for, t just displaces a bunch of empty column names. Maybe I could add a code that will allow it to display the name of the table alone itself.